# Hooking method execution in PHP

Tags: php, oop, hook

Given a base class where I have some logic that must run before and after a certain method, that takes wildly different parameters in its differing derived classes.
As an example:

```
abstract class Base{    
    public function pre(){ print "Runing Base::pre()\n"; }
    public function pos(){ print "Runing Base::post()\n"; }
    abstract public function doIt();
}

class Cheating extends Base
{
    public function doIt(){
        $this->pre();
        print "Doing it the cheating way\n";
        $this->pos();
    }
}
```

But what I'd actually like to do is along the lines of:

```
class Alpha extends Base
{
    public function doIt($x, $y){
        print "Doing it in Alpha with x=$x, y=$y";
    }
}

class Beta extends Base
{
    public function doIt($z){
        print "Doing it in Alpha with z=$z";
    }
}
```

And have some way to always run the pre and pos methods, without having to change the doIt method itself.

The obvious way, should doIt be homogenous across all derivations of Base would be something like:

```
abstract class Base
{
    public function pre(){ print "Runing Base::pre()\n"; }
    public function pos(){ print "Runing Base::post()\n"; }

    public function process($a,$b){
        $this->pre();
        $this->doIt($a,$b);
        $this->pos();
    }

    abstract public function doIt();
}

class Wishful extends Base
{
    public function doIt($a, $b){
        print "Doing it the Wishful way with a=$a, b=$b\n";
    }
}
```

The problem there is that since we have different number and type of parameters on each implementation of doIt, it does not actually solve the problem.

This sounds like a case for "hooks" - how does one go about implementing those ? Or any other decent way of solving the problem... I believe there should be a simpler way that I'm just missing - probably thinking in circles one the wrong things.

Thanks!

Comment: Make your methods private and execute them using the magic method __call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling with variable arguments can be done with: http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php. Pass $this as object.

Fetching the arguments is a bit trickier, but can be done with __call: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.methods

Comment: Pretty much, it looks a bit messy to me, but oh well... PHP does not exist to satisfy my delicate aesthetics :) Thanks, that will solve it.

Comment: :) I would go as far as saying it's really UGLY :> Compare it with a wrapper method written in python..

Answer (score 2):

You should look at [aspect-oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming). The [lithium framework's filter](http://dev.lithify.me/drafts/source/en/02_lithium_basics/02_filters.wiki) system uses such thing. [Zend Framework 2](http://www.slideshare.net/weierophinney/zend-framework-20-patterns-tutorial) also plans to use AOP.

If you want to intercept a function call at the engine level, you could use [intercept](http://pecl.php.net/package/intercept) from the PECL.

Google also reveals a [nice framework](http://marcelog.github.com/Ding/) you could LEARN a lot from. Look at its code.

Also, here is a relevant SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738282/are-there-any-working-aspect-oriented-php-libraries

Comment: Cool. I'll take a look. Ars longa, vita brevis... and deadlines - but in all likelihood it'll be worth it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want something like:

```
function process()
{
  $this->pre();
  $result = call_user_func_array( array( $this, 'doIt' ), func_get_args() );
  $this->post();
  return $result;
}
```

Comment: Sounds that way. A bit grungy but... hey, if it does it, it does it - thanks!